# How to increase or decrease specific regex numbers in a file using a macOS Shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to write a shell script where I, in an XML file, search for specific numbers using regex and simultaneously increase or decrease these numbers collectively via a predetermined variable. The script should write these to the file in one go.

For the file `test.xml`, I can find the numbers using sed. But I am sure I need to use *awk* on macOS to replace these with a calculation. Yet, I am not very good at using *awk*:

```
sed -E -i "" "s/(textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_)([0-9]+)/\1\2/g" "path to/test.xml"
```

So for the example above, I would need to add or subtract something to every `\2` in my regex substitution based on a variable, then save all the changes to the file. So that the occurrences (as an example):

```
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_12
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_13
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_14
```

…with the calculation variable `+4` will change them to:

```
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_16
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_17
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_18
```

I have tried using a calculation like this one:

```
sed -E -i "" "s/(textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_)([0-9]+)/\1$((\2+4))/ge" "path to/test.xml"
```

But that does not seem to work on Mac's sed command. As stated above, I need the adding or subtracting variable to be anything. Like `+1`, `-3`, `-9` or `+12`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Perl to the rescue: `perl -i -pe 's/textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_\K[0-9]+/$& + 4/ge' "path to/test.xml"`

Comment: Ah, thank you, @WiktorStribiżew, but I would rather avoid using Perl…

Comment: Well, you just can't use FreeBSD sed for this, you might get an `awk` answer though.

Comment: If there are lines in your input that you don't want changed, include them in your sample input/output.

Comment: What is the meaning of _write these to the file in one go_?

Comment: My apologies - I am not strong in Shell scripting and the lingo in general. What I meant was that it should simply overwrite the original file.

Comment: FYI the OPs real input doesn't look like the example in the question, see [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824242/how-to-increase-or-decrease-specific-regex-numbers-in-a-file-using-a-macos-shell/75825013?noredirect=1#comment133754298_75825013) for a hint as to what it really looks like.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I must emphasise that I was searching for a script that is flexible regarding whatever comes before the numbers I would like to change. Whether underscores, spaces, equal signs, etcetera delimit that. Once more, I am sorry that it didn't shine through in my original post. I am not well versed in this landscape.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v n=4 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$NF+=n} 1' file
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_16
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_17
textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_18
```

If, unlike the example in your question, your input actually includes lines you don't want to change then change `{$NF+=n}` to `/textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_/{$NF+=n}` or whatever other criteria you have for finding the lines to change.

Regarding "The script should write these to the file in one go." - no Unix text-processing tools do that, they all create a temp file. In GNU sed, BSD sed, perl, and ruby, and python you use `-i` to do that, in GNU awk you use `-i inplace` but in all cases you ARE using a temp file so instead of any of that, for portability  you can just do this with any Unix tool `tool`:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && tool file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```

so with GNU awk you can do:

```
awk -i inplace -v n=4 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$NF+=n} 1' file
```

but with the default BSD awk on MacOS or any other awk you can trivially do the equivalent:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -v n=4 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$NF+=n} 1' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I tested the macOS awk code, which worked but not quite as I wanted. Perhaps I should have included a real-life example here. What happens is that it completely erases the line where to find the number and replaces it with a 4.

Command: `tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -v n=4 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} /OpenSlideInKeynote&value=/{$NF+=n} 1' "$SOURCE" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$SOURCE"`

Line in question in my XML file: `{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "kmtrigger://macro=OpenSlideInKeynote&value=23"}}{\fldrslt `

Result: replaces the line with a `4`

Comment: Yes, should have included a real-life example here. You said you had lines like `textThatPrecedesTheNumbers_` so the script sets FS and OFS to `_`. Now you're trying to use it with lines like `{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "kmtrigger://macro=OpenSlideInKeynote&value=23"}}{\fldrslt` so of course it won't work as that doesn't look remotely like what you said your lines look like. You should accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new one if you made a mistake in describing/showing your input format as in this case.

Comment: Okay, I am very sorry, but I needed a flexible script therefore I emphasised the regex use case. Plus, I wanted to be as clear as possible in my communication. That my real-life example (which is not the exact case every time either) didn't fit the specific solution you gave me is what it is. I appreciate your help but I am in search of the flexibility a regex-style solution can give.

Comment: There's nothing inherently flexible about a regexp and we can't help you write a tool to parse text without seeing truly representative examples of the text you want to parse. Keep in mind it's always trivial to match the test you want but far harder to not match similar text you don't want. For example `.*` will match whatever text you want but it'll also match all text you don't want so unless you show us what your real text, including lines you do and don't want to match, looks like it's impossible to help you write a script that'll match what you want but not match what you don't want.

Comment: And providing sample input that specifically does NOT look like the text you really want to match and saying it IS the format of text you do want to match is completely counter-productive.

Comment: Lesson learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on a `mac` with an `OS` version anytime from past 17 years, and the file isn't too gigantic, you can even leverage the copy-and-pasting clipboard by

1. piping the entire output to `pbcopy`, and terminate this statement chain.
2. then start a ***new*** command statement with `pbpaste > file`, and skip the whole `tmp`-anything intermediary.

I dunno what the `Linux` equiv. of that command might be.

> - Minor caveat : this approach ***IS NOT*** considered `ATOM`-ic